# API integration with desktop application

Tags: rest-api, api, oauth2, connected-apps, callback

I am developing a desktop application that uses API to read data from salesforce

I understand I need to authenticate it first. But when I read for some long time to do this, I found out I need to setup a connected app and it requires `Callback URL`

But I don't have any online app/url that I can put as callback url and receive tokens with. I am just building a standalone desktop app that can read from salesforce through API. what can I do? what choices do I have to enable this? can't I receive the tokens in the `Response` header or data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you have two options. The first option is to set up a server on localhost, and listen for a connection from the browser at the end of the flow. This is often something like `https://localhost:1717/oauth/success`. This is how the Salesforce DX CLI operates. The second option is to listen to a WebView or similar component for when you land on the success URL, then read the token from the URL. This is typically `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success`, and the application just needs to wait until the WebView reaches this URL, then read the token from the URL. This is how the Apex Data Loader obtains its token. You can read more in the [User-Agent Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&type=5) documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much @sfdcfox. I feel like I can use the second one since I am afraid I can't easily learn setting up a local server in .NET.
could you please tell me if there is any way this can be done using the an API key like in google maps or firebase database where you use a key to get access from any app? since I am planning to use it for a single user... or any other flow that allows using username and password to authenticate my program through API...

Than kyou

Comment: @Abraham For passwords, you can use Password Oauth Flow or SOAP's login() call from the Partner WSDL. Both are not recommended for security reasons, since you have to store the user's username/password/security token. The JWT flow is similar to the "key" method you asked about. Easier to implement, but more work for the users. The WebView method is actually pretty simple, I'd recommend it. The local server method isn't much worse, actually, a quick tutorial should be all you need.